# Webpage will display only if comes from a specific page

Tags: php

I have a webform in my HOMEPAGE that accepts a code from my site visitors.

This code will be submitted to CHECKCODE.php script..

What I want is, if a user submits an invalid code, he will be redirected to SORRY.php if the code is VALID, he will be redirected to SUBMIT-INFO.php this page has a new form.

I do not want my site visitors to have a direct access to SUBMIT-INFO.php.. ,

I want SUBMIT-INFO.php to be accessible only if redirected only from CHECKCODE.php

Anyone wants to share a code I can put on SUBMIT-INFO.php ? Thanks..

Comment: There is no actual "from" in HTTP; the "HTTP referer" is highly unreliable. You could use session for this - write a value into the session in your `CHECKCODE.php` script, and in the following scripts check if that value is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I'm thinking to accomplish what you want is by using `SESSION` variables.

CHECKCODE.php

```
<?php
// start the session
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['came-from-checkcode-page']="true";
?>
<html>
<body>    
</body>
</html>
```

SUBMITINFO.php

```
<?php
// start the session
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['came-from-checkcode-page'] == "true")
{
    echo "you came from checkcode page !";
}
else{
    echo "access denied";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```